# UITableview crashes when scrolling up in Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data

I am having this crash when trying to scroll up my tableview. My array is not nil. Why does it crash every time I try to scroll up? I am trying to display data from Core Data.

Here is my code:

```
var product = [NSManagedObject]()

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return product.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cellIdentifier = "CheckOutTableViewCell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CheckOutTableViewCell

    let item = product[indexPath.row]
```

** It crashes here, every time I try to scroll up my table view

```
    cell.productTitle.text = item.valueForKey("name") as! String
    cell.productDescription.text = item.valueForKey("size") as! String

    return cell

}

func fetch() {
    let moc = DataController().managedObjectContext
    let productFetch = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Product")

    do {
        let fetchedResults: [NSManagedObject] = try moc.executeFetchRequest(productFetch) as! [Product]
        if let results: [NSManagedObject] = fetchedResults {

            product = results
            print("results:\(results.count)")
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

Product.swift

```
import Foundation
import CoreData


class Product: NSManagedObject {

}
```

Product+CoreDataProperties.swift

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

extension Product {

@NSManaged var id: String?
@NSManaged var name: String?
@NSManaged var img: String?
@NSManaged var quantity: String?
@NSManaged var size: String?
@NSManaged var price: String?
@NSManaged var promo: String?

}
```

[Crash Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08m43.png)

Comment: Can you add the crash logs ?

Comment: @ArnaudChrist i edited with screenshot on top, pls have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the size of the array before getting your product, and use optional binding (`if let`) to check that the value exists in the dictionary:

```
if indexPath.row < product.count {
    let item = product[indexPath.row]
    if let name = item.valueForKey("name") as? String {
        cell.productTitle.text = name
    }
    if let size = item.valueForKey("size") as? String {
        cell.productDescription.text = size
    }
}
```

To write safer code, it's a good idea to avoid force unwrapping when possible.

In this case, given that you have a `Product` class for your model, you should store your products as `[Product]`, you can then avoid using `valueForKey`:

```
if indexPath.row < product.count {
    let item = product[indexPath.row]
    if let name = item.name as? String {
        cell.productTitle.text = name
    }
    if let size = item.size as? String {
        cell.productDescription.text = size
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `valueForKey` when you have a `Product` class? Can't you just access your property on your model object?

Comment: Can you post your `Product` class definition?